# JavaScript AWSDate and AWSTime format to insert on db

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have two inputs, one of type date and one of type time.

The first one returns the date. For example, `2020-08-27`

The second one returns the hour. For example, `23:04`

I have two fields which are of type AWSDate and AWSTime:

```
date: AWSDate
time: AWSTime
```

I need to insert these into a mutation, how can I format these to `ISO 8601`?

I know with the date is with `toISOString()`:

```
new Date('2020-08-27').toISOString(); // 2020-08-27T00:00:00.000Z
```

But for the hour of type `AWSTime`, what's the correct method? Thank you!

Comment: If my answer isn't what you're looking for I'll remove it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand you correctly. You want a single ISOString from the individual date and time values.

```
new Date('2020-08-27 23:04').toISOString()
```

Comment: Yeah, but I need to save the date and the hour separately. Is there a method that returns me the date in ISO and the hour in ISO?

Comment: I don't think you'd want to do that but to answer your question no. There's no such thing as an `ISO Date` and an `ISO Time`. There's simply just a date string in an ISO format which includes date and time.

Comment: In that case, what's the best way to take the hour and the date based on that method?

Comment: You could definitely split the ISO string but again I don't know what benefit that would provide. You can save the date and time in their own individual formats and then if you need to combine them you can do so with the Date API.

Comment: What's the purpose behind wanting separate date and times in an ISO format?

Comment: So, the best approach is to save the date and time in one field as an ISO? And if I need them separately, I just need to split it?

Comment: Yes 100% you should save a single value - ISO String - and if you ever to get just the date or just the time from that ISO string you easily can.

Comment: Thank you! Just I wanted to know that! God bless you :)

Comment: `new Date(ISOstring).getHours() + ':' + new Date(ISOstring).getMinutes()`

Comment: Glad i could help!

Comment: Beware of timezones - if you reverse this you need to make sure you do something like new Date(new Date().toLocaleDateString()).toISOString().split("T")[0]

Answer (score 0):

AWSDate = "yyyy-mm-dd",
AWSTime = "12:30Z"

examples to enter in appsync console and try